# SQL need advice with substring and charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following string `'Custom Code changed from (JA) to (JC)'`.

I want to extract `JA` into a `column` and `JC` into another.

I have managed to get the first bracket using

```
  SUBSTRING(Call_Note_Note, CHARINDEX('(', Call_Note_Note + '(') + 1, 
  CHARINDEX(')', Call_Note_Note + '()') - CHARINDEX('(', Call_Note_Note + '(') - 1) as 'first'
```

I cant figure out how to use a simular query to extract the second part?

any help would be great!

**Extra**
There can be two formats on with one bracket and another with two brackets see below.

```
Custom Code (POO) Added
Custom Code changed from (POO) to (JA)
```

Aron

Comment: What do you know about the input strings? Are they always like your example except for the two two-letter codes changing? If so, you can simply extract two strings since you already know the exact positions. Are they always preceded by `from (` and `to (`? Then search for those. Could the string be in French? Sorry, mate.

Comment: thank you for all of your comments, there can be two format types see below. Custom Code (POO) Added
Custom Code changed from (POO) to (JA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it will always have only two codes.

Here's how you can do it using the [REVERSE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) function. This will return the first and last:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Custom Code changed from (JA) to (JC)' 

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('(', @String + '(') + 1,CHARINDEX(')', @String + '()') - CHARINDEX('(', @String + '(') - 1) as 'first',  
      REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@String), CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(@String) + '(') + 1, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@String) + ')(') - CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(@String) + ')') - 1)) as 'Second'
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be(More Readable)

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)='Custom Code changed from (JA) to (JC)';

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT @str AS string)
SELECT Substring(string, fst + 1, scd - fst - 1) as first_val,
       Substring(string, trd + 1, fou - trd - 1) as second_val
FROM   cte
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('(', string))) cs (fst)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex(')', string, fst + 1))) cs1 (scd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex('(', string, scd + 1))) cs2 (trd)
       CROSS apply (VALUES (Charindex(')', string, trd + 1))) cs3 (fou)
```

**Result:**

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ first_val ║ second_val ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ JA        ║ JC         ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you i didnt even know there was such a join as CROSS apply!, would i need to do a subquery for items with only one bracket?